# Auto detect CSS3 and switch jQuery animation/CSS3 transition

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any plugin or code that allow to write lets say

```
$('something').move('left':'50px');
```

and will detect if browser supports CSS3 transition and will use them or normal jQuery animation if CSS3 is not supported?

Comment: I searched Google for "jquery animate css transitions" and came up with all kinds of solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is, [jQuery animate enhanced](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/).

It falls back to jQuery's JS-based animation where CSS3 transitions are not available.